# SHA1 or AES - which is better in asp.net?

Tags: encryption, machinekey

which is better used in MachineKey for 3.5 framework in asp.net?

and what is the reason why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SHA1 and AES are two different things. SHA1 is a cryptographic hash algorithm while AES is a symmetric cypher.

Basically, SHA1 creates a "digest" of a message. The digest is a one-way hash that has a very small possibility of being anything like the hash generated for a similar but different message.

AES is a symmetric cipher used to encrypt data, and decrypt encrypted data. You give it a key, and it used that key and the algorithm to encrypt and decrypt data.

SHA1 is used to verify the integrity of a message, while AES is used to encrypt messages.

Comment: i guessed i asked the wrong question, but good explanation Jesse.

my dilemma is which algorithm to use in machinekey "Validation" and "Decryption" methods. in 3.5 they only offer "AES|SHA1|3DES|MD5" which i personally think it's between "AES" and "SHA1"

Comment: Weird choice, but without knowing anything about asp.net I would go for aes because it's the only one offering verification (Mac) and decryption, and is considered safe for use.